# Combining multiple crossfilter datasets

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I am building visualizations from a large dataset using dc.js. Due to each size, I have had to precompute aggregates for each dimension. Each of these has an api call, from an original data:

> hospital, diagnostic, cost, number_of_days (simplified)

I have now:

> hospital, diagnostic, cost, count

and

> hospital, diagnostic, number_of_days, count

My question is, is there a way using crossfilter.js to combine both datasets, so that when I build the visualizations using dc.js they are connected?

In other words, according to the examples, each of these should be a different call to the API, and be stored in a different crossfilter object.

Thank you,